# How to arrange panels in ggplot2 facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I am working with this data set in R

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g28etd2wywuu7on/Measurements.csv

I have done the following data manipulation

```
`dat<-read.csv("Measurements.csv")`

summarySE <- function(data=NULL, measurevar, groupvars=NULL, na.rm=FALSE,
                  conf.interval=.95, .drop=TRUE) 

{require(plyr)

  # New version of length which can handle NA's: if na.rm==T, don't count them
  length2 <- function (x, na.rm=FALSE) {
    if (na.rm) sum(!is.na(x))
    else       length(x)
  }

  # This does the summary. For each group's data frame, return a vector with
  # N, mean, and sd
  datac <- ddply(data, groupvars, .drop=.drop,
                 .fun = function(xx, col) {
                   c(N    = length2(xx[[col]], na.rm=na.rm),
                     mean = mean   (xx[[col]], na.rm=na.rm),
                     sd   = sd     (xx[[col]], na.rm=na.rm)
                   )
                 },
                 measurevar
  )

  # Rename the "mean" column    
  datac <- rename(datac, c("mean" = measurevar))

  datac$se <- datac$sd / sqrt(datac$N)  # Calculate standard error of the mean

  # Confidence interval multiplier for standard error
  # Calculate t-statistic for confidence interval: 
  # e.g., if conf.interval is .95, use .975 (above/below), and use df=N-1
  ciMult <- qt(conf.interval/2 + .5, datac$N-1)
  datac$ci <- datac$se * ciMult

 return(datac)
}

    summary.total<-summarySE(dat, measurevar="length", groupvars=c("Genotype",  "Concentration"))
pd <- position_dodge(.1)
```

### Question

I then want to plot the data, and facet in rows according to the label in the Bgrnd column.
Using ggplot2 I have done this, but get an error message. I can't figure out how to get this to work.

```
ggplot(summary.total, aes(x=Concentration, y=length, colour=Genotype, group=Genotype)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=length-se, ymax=length+se), colour="black", width=.3,     position=pd) +
  geom_line(position=pd) +
  geom_point(position=pd, size=3) +
  facet_grid(Bgrnd ~ .) +
  ylab("leaf segment width (mm)") +
  xlab("[Br]") +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=14,face="bold"), axis.text = element_text(size=13))
```

Comment: your `summary.total` doesnot have `Bgrnd` variable, does it?

Comment: Can you recreate this problem without using the exact data set?  I.e. use one of R's built in data sets like `?mtcars` or make up a data set using `rnorm` `sample` etc?